# Get object in LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

There
I want to get file's name which in LINQ Expression (I'm not sure if it is OK ask like this)

Please look at the code, find "*HERE HOW TO GET THE FILE'S NAME IN DB???*"

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(List<string> srcFiles)
{
    var filePaths = new List<string>();
    using (var db = new ContentMgmtContext())
    {
        foreach (var fileInfo in srcFiles.Select(file => new FileInfo(file)))
        {
            if (db.Files.Any(o => o.FileName.ToLower() == fileInfo.Name.ToLower() || o.FileSize == fileInfo.Length.ToString())) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} already exist in DB", fileInfo.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Conflict file in DB is: {0}",HERE HOW TO GET THE FILE'S NAME IN DB???);
            }
            else
            {
                filePaths.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
    return filePaths;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to save the new content in the DB? If so you'll need to add objects to the `DbSet` and then tell the context to `SaveChanges`.

Comment: so files with same size are considered equal?

Comment: @Richard Here I don't want to save any info into DB, but just compare some files' info with files in DB, if file's size or name are the same, they are considered equal. My question is how to get  o.FileName when files are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try collecting every db entry that matches your criteria first

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(List<string> srcFiles)
{
    var filePaths = new List<string>();
    using (var db = new ContentMgmtContext())
    {
        foreach (var fileInfo in srcFiles.Select(file => new FileInfo(file)))
        {
            var matches = db.Files.Where(o => o.FileName.ToLower() == fileInfo.Name.ToLower() ||
                o.FileSize == fileInfo.Length.ToString())

            if (matches.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var match in matches)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} already exist in DB", fileInfo.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Conflict file in DB is: {0}",match.FileName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                filePaths.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
    return filePaths;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To retain the matching object from the database you'll need to replace the `Any` operator with something that returns a match. For exmple

```
var match = db.Files.FirstOrDefault(o 
            => o.FileName.ToLower() == fileInfo.Name.ToLower() 
                || o.FileSize == fileInfo.Length.ToString());
if (match != null) {
  // Found...
}
```